# How do I detect a render event in a form using JSF?

Tags: ajax, jsf

consider the following form in a JSF page:

```
<h:form id="countForm">
  <h:outputText value="#{myBean.count}" />
  <h:commandButton value="Increment the count!">
    <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.increment()}" render="@form" />
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

This simple code will increment the counter whenever the user clicks the button, via ajax requests.

Suppose I'd also like to show the user an alert informing the new value of the counter whenever the form is updated (rerendered). How would I do that? Is there anything like the code below?

```
<h:form onUpdate="alert('the new value is #{myBean.count()}')">
```

I know I could use the "oncomplete" method of primefaces, but the event would be linked to the button instead of the form, that's not what I want.

A counter is not what I'm trying to do, this is just a simple example to better show my problem.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its difficult to provide a exact answer because your exact requirement is not clear.
1. Did you try the `<a4j:form>` which has `onComplete` event? Didn't it solve your problem?
2. If you absolutely need to run the script after the form is **reRendered** you can put `<script>` tags inside the form and put the javascript code inside them as below.

```
<h:form id="frm">
  <script>
    alert('#{myBean.count()}');
  </script>
</h:form>
```

This alert is displayed each time the form is rendered.
Note that if you need to prevent this JS run at page loading you may need to add a condition as below.

```
<head>
  <script>
    var showAlert = false;
  </script>
</head> 
<body>
<h:form id="frm">
  <script>
    if(showAlert) {
      alert('#{myBean.count()}');
    }
    showAlert = true;
  </script>
</h:form>
</body>
```

Comment: OP isn't using Ajax4jsf, OP is using JSF2.

Comment: 1. The oncomplete event is executed when the ajax request of a specific component is completed, if I have multiple components that update my form I'd have to set the oncomplete in each one of them. I'd like to link my javascript action to the render event of my form and not use "oncomplete" at all.

Comment: 2. That's exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you very much for the answer! It's not very clean to write a script inside a form, but it works fine, it will be executed everytime the form gets rendered! Just to be more clear, I don't know if you already worked with Tapestry from Apache, everytime a component gets updated it triggers  an event, the event is linked to the updated component, so it's easy to add a behavior whenever something specific is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ajax status tag component from [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/ajaxStatusStandard.jsf): `<p:ajaxStatus>` or [RichFaces](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=status&skin=blueSky): `<a4j:status>` (link to [its documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Processing_management.html#sect-Component_Reference-Processing_management-a4jstatus)). Both components handle the start and complete events from an ajax call made in the form.

I haven't tried any of these in a JSF 2 application, but I would recommend using the PrimeFaces one (at least the documentation is better than RichFaces). I've used the RichFaces `<a4j:status>` in a JSF 1.2 + RichFaces 3.3 application to show/hide a dialog to the user for any ajax request. It looked like this (and could give you an idea):

```html
<a4j:status onstart="Richfaces.showModalPanel('mdpWaitMessage')" 
    onstop="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('mdpWaitMessage')" />
<!-- defining the modal (popup) panel to show the user there was an ajax action -->
<rich:modalPanel id="mdpWaitMessage" resizeable="false" zindex="5000"
    minHeight="30" minWidth="10" height="70" width="150">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{aplicacion.waitMessageTitle}" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:graphicImage value="#{aplicacion.waitMessagePath}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{aplicacion.waitMessageDescription}" />
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Comment: ajaxStatus is not ideal, but it works. It's not ideal because this event is linked to every ajax request, not just the ones that updates the form. To do what I want with ajaxStatus I should set "global = false" (primefaces) to every ajax request in my page that does not update the form. It's not the best solution but it is one, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `javax.faces.event.PreRenderComponentEvent.`

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <f:event type="preRenderComponent"
           listener="#{someActionListener}" />
</h:form>
```

Each time you (re-)render your form, the actionListener will be called first.

Comment: I guess OP asks to execute a JavaScript method when an ajax method gets executed, not another server side method.

Comment: Luiggi is right, I don't want to call another server-side method, I want just to execute a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way that is not greatly elegant, but I am using it in scenario where I am stuck with no other alternative. I am using a `<h:panelGroup>` that contains a `<script>` block, and I use the panelGroup id in the `render=` part of the `<f:ajax` part

```
<h:form id="countForm">
  <h:outputText value="#{myBean.count}" />
  <h:commandButton value="Increment the count!">
    <f:ajax listener="#{myBean.increment()}" render="postAjax" />
  </h:commandButton>
  <h:panelGroup id="postAjax">
    <script>
     //...
    </script>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Note this will not work well if the `panelGroup` is inside a `ui:repeat` or `datatable`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer JScoobyCed, but that's not what I'm looking for. I think to do what you're trying to do, the "oncomplete" method from primefaces would work better, instead of using the f:ajax and "render" you could use p:ajax and assign your script to the "oncomplete" event. It doesn't work in my case because my form can be updated by different components, I want the same script to be executed whenever it happens without having to set "oncomplete" in every component.